# Update table rows another table rows in vb.net as per id

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two table like tab1 & tab2 and use a common iD. Now need to update tab2 rows.

tab2

```
id----|--Name-|--Designation|--intime--|--outtime--|  
152--|--jon----|-------IT-------|00:00:00 |00:00:00 |  
153--|--Jac---|------Admin---|00:00:00 |00:00:00 |
```

tab1

```
id----|-intime--|--outtime--|  
152--|09:40:00 |08:00:00 |  
153--|09:35:00 |08:00:00 |
```

now a need to update like this:

```
id----|--Name-|--Designation|--intime--|--outtime--|  
152--|--jon----|-------IT-------|09:40:00 |08:00:00 |  
153--|--Jac---|------Admin---|09:35:00 |08:00:00 |
```

tab2 intime/outtime update tab1 intime/outtime condition by id

Approx 500 id need to update

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: It is not clear if you want to execute some update in database tables or if you want to do this with two memory DataTable objects. Could you clarify this point?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this

```
Update T
SET T.intime = S.intime,
    T.outtime = S.outtime
FROM tab2 T JOIN tab1 S ON
    T.id =S.id
```